# WebStorm error: expression statement is not assignment or call

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm and I'm getting an error that I can't understand. Node.js + MongoDB.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(' mongodb://localhost:27017/TodoApp');

var Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', {
    text: {
        type: String
    },
    completed: {
        type: Boolean
    },
    completedAt: {
        type: Number
    }
});

var newTodo = new Todo({
    text: 'Cook dinner'
});
```

The problem is in this block:

```
newTodo.save().then((doc) => {
    console.log('Saved todo', doc);
}, (e) => {
    console.log('Unable to save todo')
})
```

P.S.: The code works fine.

Comment: `console.log('Unable to save todo')` doesn't have a semicolon `;` ?

Comment: semicolon will give just warning so it does not matter @YashKaranke. Many coding styles does even follow no semicolon rule.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to change JavaScript Language Version to ES6. Changing this setting should fix the issue:

[image: Settings to change Javscript version to ES6]

In some scenarios, you might need to restart your IDE for the changes to reflect properly.

Comment: gauravmuk answer is correct, pay attention that you can change the Javascript from the Webstorm->Preferences menu and not from the File->Default Settings. The second one has no effect on your current project

Comment: Considering the current approval state of ES6, can this be taken as a general recommendation for JSX based projects?

Comment: This answer is __NOT__ correct as I have my settings set to Ecmascript 6, but I still get the warning.

Comment: @Jim I saw the same thing and restarting the IDE fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I did not even restart whole IDE. Only changed option 'Only type-based..' ON and OFF and it fixed problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This also works for IntelliJ IDEA (2018). But the preferences are called "settings": File -> Settings... (Ctrl+Alt+S).
I therefore added the Intellij Tag :-)

Comment: What if I want React JSX, which I do?

Comment: I have 6+ and still get that warning. In `this.currentExercise = this.availableExercises.find( (exercise: Exercise)  => {exercise.id === exerciseId});`

Answer (score 24):

The problem is that WebStorm will show a warning if that statement ***isn't doing*** any of the following within a function:

- Calling another function
- Making any sort of assignment
- Returning a value
- (There may be more, but those are the ones I know of)

In other words, ***WebStorm views*** that function as unnecessary and tries to help you catch unused code.

For example this will show the warning:

```js
const arr = [1, 2];
const willShowWarning = arr.map(num => {
    num + 1;
});
```

Adding a return will take the warning away:

```js
const arr = [1, 2];
const willNotShowWarning = arr.map(num => {
    return num + 1;
});
```

The answer is *not* to change WebStorm settings.