# When I try to use ``` ...``` decorator doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to do this : 
`setMyState(prevState=> {...prevState, name: e.nativeEvent.text });`

While the console says `src/components/addItem.js: Unexpected token`
And it doesn't work :( 
While using a js file .. I tried with .jsx too and same error :(. 
Also I found an  answer here [WebStorm error: expression statement is not assignment or call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44618100/webstorm-error-expression-statement-is-not-assignment-or-call) 
but it didn't solve my problem since when I run the app now it crashes exactly there ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use an arrow function and want to [return an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals) you need to wrap your object with `()`. If you don't use, arrow function thinks `{}` is the body block. So, try using:

```
setMyState(prevState=> ({...prevState, name: e.nativeEvent.text }));
```

Comment: Upsi ou are right .. my bad :D

Comment: @Alessandro Shouldn't it be `setMyState((prevState => ({...prevState, name: e.nativeEvent.text }))());` ? Why I feel it's only passing the function not the object that it's trying to produce?

Comment: Oh nvm, both way works

Comment: @HaoWu, this is how `setMyState` works here. It takes a function and returns something for the state as being updated. You don't need to invoke it.